# What does reputation represent?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Because I wasn't thinking about it I always took reputation as to how active you are on an SE-site.

I now thought about it and came to the conclusion that it basically shows that you asked or answered popular questions on popular subjects.

One example: It does not say anything about the quality or the complexity of a discussed subject. On the contrary the more complex a question/answer is, the less it gets upvotes (there are exceptions of course)

How could we describe the meaning of reputation to someone who doesn't know Stack Exchange's principle?

Comment: Take my rep, subtract yours, and that's how much better I am than you.  Simple!

Comment: @Will not necessarily better, reputation score != expertise it could mean you have more spare time to write up answers for instance.

Comment: It's much more intelligent indication than just of your activity.

Comment: @JonH, I think Will's statement was a bit facetious.

Comment: Should of known its THAT WILL! :).

Comment: @JonH no, I meant how much better *as a human being* I am.  It's okay that you misunderstood.  Seeing what your rep is, and all.

Comment: @Will I got `L0 8A77`, what does that mean?

Comment: This is directly answered in the [SO help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), in the first sentence: "Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about."

Comment: Jeff Atwood's words: "reputation measures how much the system trusts you".  Makes a lot of sense, you get to do riskier things the more rep you get.

Comment: How many unicorns I can buy

Comment: @HansPassant Note that the system's trust is determined by how many [stupid questions you've asked about toasters](http://superuser.com/questions/792607/why-does-windows-think-that-my-wireless-keyboard-is-a-toaster).

Comment: @KenWhite If we'd replace "rough" with "random" we'd be closer to a correct answer to OP's question ; ).

Comment: @Teemu: If we replace "rough" with "random", that doesn't say a lot for either of us in terms of accomplishments here. I've worked to earn the rep I have by making sure I write knowledgeable answers, as well as through other contributions.

Comment: Hello everyone, and welcome to Stackoverflow, where everything's made up and the points don't matter

Comment: It means how good your Googling skills are...

Comment: How happy you are answering easy duplicates rather than flagging them...

Comment: Same as likes on Facebook, you get reputation for being in the trend, i.e. spreading whatever everybody else is talking about. Programming-wise, if you answer something about SQL, add a couple words about SQL injection - you get +2 votes.

Comment: Don't forget the badges!

Comment: It represents how many sock puppet accounts you have.

Answer (score 51):

I would say it represents the usefulness of your contribution, in terms of how many people it helped.  IE, the more people who found your contribution useful, the more upvotes you get.  Answering more popular questions usefully gives more votes, which is perfectly fine: you helped a larger number of people.

It's like the difference between writing in a student paper that a few dozen people read versus writing for the New York Times.  The latter writer doesn't have to be as 'good' - as long as the writer is good enough, a lot more people will benefit by reading their articles.  The former can write amazing articles, and is very useful to that group of people - and you can't really say one is "better" than the other - but the NYT author certainly affects more peoples' lives.

It does not:

- indicate how smart you are
- indicate how good of a programmer you are
- indicate how good your answers are (necessarily)

It does:

- indicate that you asked or answered a number of questions that were found useful by a number of people.
- make you feel better about yourself (sometimes)
- increase your imaginary internet point score
- also, [more unicorns!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-god-its-full-of-unicorns)

Comment: Rather how many people thought your answer useful, in the first sentence. Unless "how many people you helped" should include "how many people you helped stay deluded and heading to a rude awakening sometime down the line".

Comment: It's also a relatively good indicator of how much you participate in the network.

Comment: How many people thought your answer useful is exactly correct for that meaning, @Deduplicator.  Note "thought".  :)

Comment: @Compass No, it's not.  I participate a _lot_.  But I also don't get all that much rep, relatively speaking, because I post in [tag:SAS] which if you get 5 upvotes on an answer it's a miracle.  I managed to go past 20K without the Mortarboard badge, for heaven's sake.  It's a indicator of how many people found your participation useful, _not_ the participation itself.

Comment: @Joe 25.1k rep is a lot more than 2k If you recommended chocolate and I recommended vanilla, I'd bet that people would unconsciously favor chocolate <_<

Comment: Oh, I have a lot of rep, but I have a _lot_ of answers.  I participate way more than the average 25k user.  And I would recommend Strawberry.

Comment: @Joe Now I want Neapolitan ice cream.

Comment: This answer just made me feel good....Stackoverflow is a fun learning place with so many intelligent people, always ready for help.

Comment: Another note on the participation thing; I used to participate and have a lot of rep, but I barely get any time to these days and I still average ~70 rep per day.

Answer (score 10):

> How could we describe the meaning of reputation to someone who doesn't know StackExchange's principle?

Seems after all really deep thinking, **rep** and **badges** are kind of a  gamification provided at this site, and we're all just trapped enjoying it.

Though for a new user, it could be clarified that winners in the game (+rep) are agreed by the community to give good and concise answers, or ask good questions by the same means.

Comment: @Ðаn https://xkcd.com/810?

Answer (score 2):

While a lot of the time reputation is directly proportional to the usefulness of a user's contributions to others, it more accurately represents an ability to know how to convince other users in a fleeting moment to click the up arrow on your answer even if they have not entirely read or understood it. Just the act of writing a very long answer with references and quotes from other sources seems to be enough to guarantee several up votes, even if the answer doesn't necessary help the original question. However, in many cases, it does help, though not necessarily any more than a much more focused, shorter answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at what reputation represents at many  levels.

At a zoomed in level it's an incentive for users to do their best to make their answers as useful as they can for others. This way they increase their likelihood of receiving reputation (pleasure) and avoiding downvoting (pain). Even people who ask questions have the incentive of asking their question in proper and clear form or have to fear for being down-voted. Resulting in abstraction from their question and decreasing the chance of a real answer. These incentive are in the form of upvotes, replies and even down-votes. For the community and all the people who visit the site, it makes good and bad answers measurable and makes it easier to find the most valuable answer fast. Topics with more upvotes are also easier to find with the search function.

If you zoom out to a larger scale, you can also notice trending topics by viewing where the most reputation is being given. To see what's going on in the world, which real life problems are popular and which questions are important. Overall I think that when technology evolves that also the question that are being asked change in their direction, ever so slightly. The shift in interesting topics, probably also changes where you can earn the most reputation. This probably makes having a high reputation more relevant since you can assume that a person with a high reputation has real applicable day to day knowledge.

I think that the zoomed in and zoomed out perspective as described give the users a sense of belonging. Either at a zoomed in level, where you can get a good feeling for helping others and are rewarded mainly in the form of reputation (since you are not allowed to say +1 or "thanks"). At a zoomed out level it can be used as a kind of resume for even something like a job-interview to show that you're active in the field and have experience with current day problems.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down reputation into categories can be useful to measure the amount of contributions, helpfulness, unicorns, etc. of a user.

But at the end of the day, it basically represents the amount of trust a user has accumulated from the community. This is why site privileges are tied to reputation.

It is just one metric though, and should not be taken as the only consideration for a user...

Comment: ...Unless that user is @Will, in which case he is clearly a better human being than everyone else in this post.

Answer (score 0):

> I now thought about it and came to the conclusion that it basically
>   shows that you asked or answered popular questions on popular
>   subjects.

That's definitely not true in all cases. I've earned my 70k reputation by answering many, many zero and one point questions in a niche area. Out of almost 2,500 answers, perhaps only one or two percent of the questions have a two-digit score.

Answer (score -1):

Reputation mostly is gathered by up-votes to the questions and answers, about questions it shows how much your question were useful to others or others in a specific field (for example C#) (that is mostly subjective) so the reputations of the member in this case is also interpreted subjective. it means the one who is counted a useful person maybe is not a useful person for me.

Up-votes to the answers are more objective, and shows if it possess enough worth to solve the problem. If the reputations are gathered mostly from up-votes to the answers, then it means that the user could be an informative and knowledgeable (again in the field which most of his answers lay)

Answer (score -12):

Stack Overflow reputation points let people look at you with **respect**.

You get respect as you solve complicated questions where people get stuck. And thus they upvote you, and it increases your reputation points.

So indirectly, the higher the reputation, the more respect.

That's the bottomline.

Comment: When I go to the local market, no one looks at me with Respect. As a matter of fact, being an alien citizen, sometimes they look funny at me.  Maybe I should wear my badges when I go buy tomatoes :)

Comment: @brasofilo hi i m not talking with Non Techie or Non programmers , I talk about people who know you and your stackoverflow repo.

Comment: Yep, I know what you mean, but I don't think "respect" is the right concept here...

Comment: Some people upvote really simple questions, like "How does Java do really stupidly simple Java things" and everyone upvotes a very simple and general question, because they also had it and didn't research much, even though the upvote shows "this question shows research effort, is useful and clear"